# fixed horizontal navigation menu upon scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm still relatively new to the world of programming and I am currently attempting to create a website with a horizontal navigation menu that sticks to the top of the page when scrolled down.  For example I want to create something such as the menu on http://www.w3schools.com/html/   The menu is a list inside a div which itself inside another div.  I tried to change the style of the enclosing div to fixed  when the page is scrolled down with some javascript but this is very glitchy and doesn't work effectively.  Is there any other way I can do this?

This is the Javascript I am using at the bottom of the html file and the css just changes to `position : fixed;`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var header = $("#menu-wrapper");
var headerY = header.offset().top;
$(document).scroll(function () {
var y = $(document).scrollTop();

if (y >= headerY) {
    header.addClass('fixed');
} else {
    header.removeClass('fixed');
}
});`
</script>
```

Comment: There isn't any need for JavaScript, simply HTML and CSS. Can you post your code so we can help you further?

Comment: I've edited the post and added the code I am currently using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question requires to give a little use of `JQuery` to get the desired output and also contains different Design style! hence adding another Answer!

**[Here is working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Vikrant29/80nzsnnm/1/)**

### JQuery Code :

```
$("document").ready(function(){

        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 136) {
                $('.nav-container').addClass("f-nav");
            } else {
                $('.nav-container').removeClass("f-nav");
            }
        });

    });
```

### Important CSS :

```
.f-nav{ z-index: 9999; position: fixed; top: 0; width: 100%;} /* this make our menu float top */
```

Answer (score 1):

The required view can be achieved using simple `CSS3`, **no need of JavaScript at initial level**!

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Vikrant29/SkuhZ/244/)

### CSS code :

```
#cssmenu {
   position:fixed;
   top: 0;
   margin:auto;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 50px;
   background-color: #4861A3;
}
```

Comment: This works better but it covers the very top of the page underneath it and I would like it to be part of the page when scrolled to the top then to come off and stick to the top when scrolled below it's position

Comment: yes with some modifications.. you can do that as well!

Comment: Buddy @tchapple1, i m adding code of `Jquery` which is required to add to give feature that you want!

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
       var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
       var topDist = $("your container Selector").position();
       if (scroll > topDist.top) {
          $('Your Menu Seloctor').css({"position":"fixed","top":"0"});
       } else {
          $('Your Menu Seloctor').css({"position":"static","top":"auto"});
       }
   });
```

});

Above code working for fixed Menu on Scroll using Jquery. This code working even if your Navigation in middle of the page.